# Heptic programing for windows, not able to include header file

Tags: visual-c++

I am writing program for haptic device, it is in dev c++. As the programing is windows programing it is showing error that QHHeaders.h is missing . How i can include that file so that my program run?

Comment: Confusing question. Why did you tag Visual if you use Dev-C++? The latter is outdated since 2005 btw, get a proper IDE. Also, by the sound of it you're asking how to use #include? It's the first thing you learn when coding in C++ so I surely don't get the question.

Answer (score 0):

> I am writing program for haptic device, it is in dev c++. As the
>   programing is windows programing it is showing error that QHHeaders.h
>   is missing . How i can include that file so that my program run?

I imagine you must make sure that the header directory is part of your project / makefile include path.

This [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73f9s62w.aspx) explains how: